# React Native find north direction

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I'm working on a compass app and need to find current direction to a particular point (I have coordinates), or at least to the north. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who faced the same problem:

1) get access to magnetometer and accelerometer of a device. For that you can either write your own react-native <-> java/swift/objC bridge or use one of libraries like these:

github com/pwmckenna/react-native-motion-manager

github com/kprimice/react-native-sensor-manager

2) convert meters' data to compass heading.
Some informations is here:
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/AN203_Compass_Heading_Using_Magnetometers.pdf

3) If there is a need to find direction to some particular point, first you need to get your own coordinates and then adding that to point's coordinates you can find out azimuth.

Answer (score 0):

It does not support, but you can simply render a polyline annotation from your direction result.